# Presto How to use Try_Parse

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

In Presto, I am trying to parse **String** to **Date** with given **format**, However if String doesn't match to the format, query fails.

```
select date_parse('2020-01-20T16:21:09.346Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ');
```

What I am expecting here is graceful handling, so that if **date_parse** method will fail, it would return either **null** or some **default value** provided.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Try using this https://cloudjunkie.io/all-articles/2018/3/25/parsing-multiple-date-formats-in-athena#solution

Comment: @DeepakKumar Thanks, Do you wish to answer it, so that I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link resolved the issue.

https://cloudjunkie.io/all-articles/2018/3/25/parsing-multiple-date-formats-in-athena#solution

```
    SELECT TestData.FormatId, 
        Coalesce(
            try(date_parse(TestData.MultiDateCol, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')),
            try(date_parse(TestData.MultiDateCol, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s')),
            try(date_parse(TestData.MultiDateCol, '%Y/%m/%d')),
            try(date_parse(TestData.MultiDateCol, '%d %M %Y')),
            try(date_parse(TestData.MultiDateCol, '%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s')),
            try(date_parse(TestData.MultiDateCol, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')),
            try(date_parse(TestData.MultiDateCol, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'))
        )  as DateConvertedToTimestamp,
        TestData.MultiDateCol
    FROM
    (
    SELECT '2020-01-01 13:01:01' AS MultiDateCol, 'Format 1' AS FormatId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020/01/02 13:01:02', 'Format 2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020/01/03', 'Format 3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '04 JAN 2020', 'Format 4'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '05 JAN 2020 13:01:05', 'Format 5'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '06/01/2020 13:01:06', 'Format 6'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '07-01-2020 13:01:07', 'Format 7'
    ) AS TestData
    ORDER BY TestData.FormatId
```

Comment: Per SO guidelines, please a link is not an answer (e.g. answer should be useful even if the other site goes down). A link can compliment the answer, but in this case it's better to link directly to Presto docs: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try